# Vertically align a PRE block within a TD to "Top"

Tags: css

I am trying to vertically align the contents of a PRE block within a TD to "Top". I am using a CSS stylesheet file. No Luck. I can get the font colour and size to change however.

```
table td pre{
color: red;
font: normal 16px Arial;
vertical-align:top; /* Does not work */
}
```

Thoughts appreciated.

EDIT:

```
table td pre{
   color: red;
   font: normal 16px Arial;
}
table td {
   padding: 5px;
   border: solid 1px white;
   background-color: #edeff1;
   vertical-align: top;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vertical align is for `td` and not for `pre`

```
table td.preBlock{
vertical-align:top;
}

table td pre{
color: red;
font: normal 16px Arial;
}
```

Then you can do

```
<td class="preBlock">
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tZQ94/)**

**Edit:**

Seems to work for me even that way, just reduce `margin-top`. See here

**[Fiddle2](http://jsfiddle.net/tZQ94/4/)**

Comment: Thanks for this. See my EDIT above. I did try the alignment in the TD tag, but it did not seems to work.

Comment: I notice in your Fiddle that "Testing" does not go to the same level of "Topness" as Vertical-Align:top does for TD without PRE. Is the PRE acting abit like a <P> tag here, in that it has an inbuilt top margin?

Comment: Yep, I just removed top margin from Fiddle2. Try that

Comment: Thanks for this. I notice that I cannot alter the font on the PRE using a Body {} rule. This is fine for TDs, but has not effective on the PRE tag. I have to alter the TD PRE Rule to ="font:normal 12px Arial" for example. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you 0 out any top spacing on the pre element as well:

```
td {
    padding-top: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
    vertical-align: top;
}
pre {
    padding-top: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

[Fiddle example.](http://jsfiddle.net/crazytonyi/EnuBs/)